# How do I create a form that looks like it's floating on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am a beginner. I am trying to make a webpage for practice. I am trying PSD to HTML. I don't know how to make a form that looks like it's floating on a div. The height of the form is greater than the height of the div.

Here is an image of that:
[image]

I marked the area of the form with red color and the area of the div with light green color.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid py-5" style="background: #f7f7fd">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-md-5 py-5">
                    <h5>
                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Similique qui unde inventore dignissimos quia
                        dolor in neque quasi incidunt mollitia laudantium
                        nisi eveniet doloribus aliquam, quod maxime voluptas
                        quos. Dolorum.
                    </h5>
                    <div class="d-flex mt-3">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle border border-light me-3"
                            src="./images/person/Dabananda_Mitra-removebg-preview.png" alt="Dabananda Mitra"
                            style="height: 50px; width: 50px" />
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Dabananda Mitra</h5>
                            <p class="mb-0">CEO & Founder</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="d-flex justify-content-center py-5" style="background: #007bff">
                            <div class="col-11">
                                <h4 class="text-light mb-3">
                                    Free consaltation
                                </h4>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="Name" placeholder="Name:"
                                    style="border-radius: 0%" />
                                <input type="email" class="form-control mb-3" id="Email" placeholder="Email:"
                                    style="border-radius: 0%" />
                                <select class="form-select form-select mb-3" aria-label=".form-select example"
                                    style="border-radius: 0%">
                                    <option value="1">One</option>
                                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                                </select>
                                <textarea class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Message:" rows="4"
                                    style="border-radius: 0%"></textarea>
                                <button type="submit" style="
                                            background: #08237e;
                                            width: 15rem;
                                            height: 2.5rem;
                                            color: white;
                                            border: transparent;
                                        ">
                                    SEND REQUEST
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I make this type form?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDLpo.png I don't understand the question. Can you please check the attachment and verify in developer options again. The height of the div is the same.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal The form is inside the div but the height of the form is more than the height of the div in the picture. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the height of the form to be more than the div? The height of the form to be independent of the height of the div right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following css. Is this what you mean? You'll probably want to add a class to the container so you only select this div.

```css
    <style>
      .container-fluid {
        position:relative;
      }
      
      .container:before, .container:after {
        position:absolute;
        content:"";
        background-color: white;
        height:80px;
        width:100%;
        z-index: 1;        
      }

      .container:before {
        top:0;
        left:0;
      }

      .container:after {
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        
      }

      form {
        z-index:2;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Oh I just realized you could also use a gradient background.
      
.container-fluid {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 15%, rgba(51,51,51,1) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
      }